# How can I remove dynamic text from an array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string with a lot of random words: example *var stringWithWords = "hello my name is"* the separator between the words are a space.

I have also a variable var word1 = "name". (BUT its dynamic, it can change and I dont know exactly where it is in the string above).

Now the question: How can I remove word1 from the string stringWithWords ?

Comment: You can use `newStr = stringWithWords.replace(word1, '')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array = array.map(x => {
    return x.replace(name, '').trim();
})
```

That's for an array, i think you changed your question since I first read it tho...

For a string just use replace and then trim to remove unnecessary whitespace...